# Parse arbitrary Rust Debug output to a structured form

Tags: rust

How can I **heuristically** convert Debug trait output of any Rust object to some structured form (e.g. JSON) for a Human consumption?  In other words, convert `format!("{foo:?}")`, assuming `foo` recursively uses the `#[derive(Debug)]` or a similar implementation, without the ability to modify any internal code?

Suggested code/tool/site does NOT have to produce any stable output -- this functionality is needed for examining the debug output by a human, not anything automated.

I often have complex debug output, such as the example below (some internal clippy variable dump). I would like to convert it into a json to be able to easily view/collapse the tree.

```yaml
Expr {
    hir_id: HirId(DefId(0:4 ~ single_match[d315]::issue_10808).4),
    kind: Path(
        Resolved(
            None,
            Path {
                span: $DIR/single_match.rs:7:11: 7:14 (#0),
                res: Local(
                    HirId(DefId(0:4 ~ single_match[d315]::issue_10808).2),
                ),
                segments: [
                    PathSegment {
                        ident: bar#0,
                        hir_id: HirId(DefId(0:4 ~ single_match[d315]::issue_10808).5),
                        res: Local(
                            HirId(DefId(0:4 ~ single_match[d315]::issue_10808).2),
                        ),
                        args: None,
                        infer_args: true,
                    },
                ],
            },
        ),
    ),
    span: $DIR/single_match.rs:7:11: 7:14 (#0),
}
```

Comment: I would strongly advise you to not attempt this. The debug output is not designed to be parsed. Even if you parse what `#[derive(Debug)]` generates, many things don't follow that format as evidenced in your example.

Comment: Plus: "_Derived Debug formats are not stable, and so may change with future Rust versions. Additionally, Debug implementations of types provided by the standard library (std, core, alloc, etc.) are not stable, and may also change with future Rust versions._" ([link](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/fmt/trait.Debug.html#stability)). So if you do this, simply updating the toolchain may break your parser.

Comment: What you are looking for is probably `serde::Serialize` instead of `Debug`, in conjunction with `serde_json`.

Comment: @kmdreko I do NOT want this to be a stable thing -- I need this to examine the debugger output in an easier way, instead of digging through a giant plain text dump

Comment: @YuriAstrakhan *"I would like to convert it into a json to be able to easily view/collapse the tree"* -  Any text editor worth its salt should allow you to collapse based on matching `()`, `{}`, and `[]` alone. At least VSCode and Sublime Text provide it out of the box. That is a much lower bar of functionality than a conversion to JSON.

Comment: @kmdreko wow, I was not aware that vscode can collapse ANY text. I tend to use IntelliJ, and despite it supposedly being one of the best IDEs I've used, it only works with the "proper" structure like JSON (AFAIK).  If you put it as an answer, I would gladly mark it as a good answer without the more generic "dbg parser". Thx!